# How do I set admin credentials for rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

After installing and setting up devise for user login I went ahead and added the rails_admin gem. Now if I go too localhost:3000/admin I can access the admin dashboard but How do I add admin authentication so you would need to enter admin credentials to access the admin dashboard?

Comment: Check the wiki: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use an authorization gem called [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) (is the updated version of cancan) it's super easy to use and it will let you to give certain permissions to different kind of users. If you don't know nothing about this gem i will recommend you to see [this railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) that will teach you how to use it properly.

So after you installed the cancancan gem in the ability.rb file you just need to do something like this to limit the admin access

### models/ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user && user.admin?
      can :access, :rails_admin       # only allow admin users to access Rails Admin
      can :dashboard           
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all                   # allow everyone to read everything
    end
  end
end
```

And don't forget to tell to the rails_admin gem that you are using cancancan to validate the authorization

### config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  ## == Cancan ==
  config.authorize_with :cancan

end
```

To user the "user.admin?" method you must create it into the user model, but it will only work if you have a role model that has_many users and users belongs_to role otherwise you will need other way to verify the role, so it will be something like this

### models/role.rb

```
has_many :users
```

### models/user.rb

```
belongs_to :role

def admin?
  role_id == 0 # If you have id == 0 for admin
end
```

Also i will recommend you to use a role model or enum to manage the different roles with ease.

I hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.rb`

```
authenticate :admin do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => 'rails_admin', as: :rails_admin
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide your user with an admin role such that you can test, e.g.  `user.admin?`.

Configure rails_admin to inherit from your application controller and to catch any access other than a signed in admin user.

```
#config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
   ...
  config.parent_controller = 'ApplicationController'
  config.authenticate_with do
    # current_user =  User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    raise InvalidAdminAccess, 'Access denied.' unless current_user.try(:admin?)
  end
end
```

Define the `InvalidAdminAccess` error class in

```
# app/errors/invalid_admin_access.rb
class InvalidAdminAccess < StandardError
end
```

Catch the error in your application controller

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  rescue_from InvalidAdminAccess do |exception|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
      format.html { redirect_to main_app.root_url, alert: exception.message }
      format.js   { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
    end
  end
end
```

In this way, when there is incorrect access, `rails_admin` triggers an exception that is caught and handled by the application controller.